# Blazor WASM displaying resource key instead of localized value

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to implement localization in my Blazor WebAssembly app, by following one of tutorials found on internet, such as:
[Localization in Blazor](https://code-maze.com/localization-in-blazor-webassembly-applications/)

I have set up everything described in tutorials, but I cannot get a localized value for a specific key, I get a KEY displayed as text I want to localize.

Here is my code:
Program.cs - hardcoded culture, to make sure i choose the right one:

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Localization"; });
var culture = new CultureInfo("sr");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

In my .razor file I injected a IStringLocalizer:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<General> localizer
```

And I use a localizer like this:
<MudTooltip Text="@localizer["Open"]">

My Class generated from .resx is called General.
Here is my resources setup: Added a resx as Embedded resource and code gen tool PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
[image: Main resources file for 'en']

My localized resx for Serbian language is set as EmbeddedResource and with no code generation tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IStringLocalizer<T>` doesn't rely on a generated class from the `.resx` file. During the build process, the `ResourceManager`embeds the resource in the main dll and creates satellite dlls. The default implementation of `IStringLocalizer<T>` rely on the `ResourceManager` to read the files inside the assembly or satellite assembly. So turn off the code generation should solve your problem.

[image: Properties of a .resx files]

Update:

The `<T>` is referring to any possible class. There is no constraint enforce. However, there should be a link between the namespace of the class and the file location.

Assume you have the file `Pages/Users/AddUserPage.razor`

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<AddUser> Localizer
```

If you don't specify a namespace manually, `AddUserPage` class will end up in the namespace `<ProjectRootNamespace>.Pages.Users`.

So, you need to create a .resx file reflecting the folder structure. Your root is specified as `Localization` so you need to create the file `Localization/Pages/Users/AddUserPage.resx` or and their locazied counterparts like `Localization/Pages/Users/AddUserPage.sr.resx`

In some cases, it makes sense to group certain localization, like the caption of buttons (Ok, Close, Yes, No, etc.). To avoid having these keys in each .resx file, you can create an empty class. I like to name it `SharedRessources`. However, the name is not important as long as you name your .resx file accordingly.

```
namespace <ProjectRootNamespace>
{
    public class SharedRessources
    {
    }
}
```

Because the class is in the root namespace of your project, the .resx file should be placed inside the root folder of your .resx file. In your case, `Localization`. So, the name should be `Localization/SharedRessources.resx` and `Localization/SharedRessources.sr.resx`

Now, you can this can be injected too.

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<AddUser> Localizer
@inject IStringLocalizer<SharedRessources> SharedLocalizer

<p> Hi from @Localizer["KeyLocalToAddUser"] </p>
<p> Do you want to delete the user? <span> @SharedLocalizer["No"] or SharedLocalizer["Yes"]
```

Comment: So T is for what? I tried to put my page's class name for T, and I did like you proposed - no code generation, but still not working. I also read some articles that there should not be a default resource file - tried that - no luck...

Comment: Looks like I did not follow the naming rules for resource files:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#resource-file-naming
So if I had a page named Playlists, a resource file should be named "Pages.Playlists.xx.resx  I am not sure if this should be an answer, I am curious if there is a way to group localized strings in something bigger than a page.

Comment: There is an answer for my previous comment in the same article. A dummy class should be used to group shared resources.

Comment: Thanks for your input @vpetrovic. I've updated the answer with more information about T, the naming convention and how to handle sharing of localization between multiple pages